# how to interrupt from command line an rtsp registration

Tags: command-line, vlc, video-recording

I'm using cvlc to register an rtsp stream.
Is there a way to control cvlc from command line, to stop its recording in a clean way.

The options stop-time or run-time are not useful because in my case,
because each time I run a recording, I want to be free to stop recording when needed.

Comment: I usually run `killall cvlc` or `killall vlc`which should be fine because it sends a SIGTERM by default and I never had any issues because of that. But a proper solution would be better.